# DIV using CSS layout Basic

Tags: css, html

hi guys i'm trying to create a layout and understand  using CSS and div. it seems like i'm having a hard time making the center column fixed in the center, cause everytime i type a long text it exceeds the right column, what's the best way to avoid this? Any easier method to use to understand? i'm beginner and i used to use TABLES AND TD's, it's easier to understand, but i'm trying to catch up with divs cause tables and rows seems obsolete. Please help thanks.

Here's my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/CVXKn/2/

```
<div id="wrapper" align="center">

        <div id="wrapper_inner">

            <div id="menubar">MENU BAR GOES HERE</div>

            <div id="headerContainer">Header LOGO Goes here</div>

            <div id="bodyContainer">

                <div id="left"> </div>

                <div id="center"> gegggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</div>
                    <div id="centerEnter"> </div>

                <div id="right"> </div>
                <div class="clear"> </div>

            </div>   

            <div id="footerContainer">Footer Goes Here</div>

         </div>

     </div>
```

Comment: Tables are not obsolete, they are just best used with tabular data.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `word-wrap` property on `#center` to `break-word`.

```
#center
{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVXKn/4/)**</kbd>

Here's a link to information about [`word-wrap`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS, this will break long words

```
#center {
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

In the CSS of the center div should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're using a single unbroken "word" to test your layout. A sentence will be cut off when there isn't enough space for the next word and will force a new line and keep going til there's no more text.

As others have pointed out, if you need to use lots of big words that'll break your layout use `word-wrap: break-word;` to break them where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css

```
#center {
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```